# value OK is not a member of String (using Dispatch and Scalatra)

Tags: scala, scalatra, dispatch-async

I am trying a simple example where I am using a modification of the Dispatch example from the [Scalatra site](http://www.scalatra.org/2.4/guides/async/akka.html) to make an async http request. The code is below. I get a compilation error that says value OK is not a member of String. I put together a standalone scala test with no Scalatra dependencies and it works as expected. I suspect OK is being pulled in from some Scalatra dependency. 
I am new to Scala and I am putting together a test web app using Scalatra. Any help will be appreciated.

```
import dispatch._

trait AppAPIStack extends AppStack {
before() {
  contentType = "application/json"
}

object MyAsyncClient {

   def sendReq(phrase: param): Future[String] = {
     val searchURL = url("https://www.google.com/#q="+phrase)
     val result = dispatch.Http(searchURL OK as.String)
     for(r <- result) yield r
   }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the issue by changing the line

```
url("https://www.google.com/#q="+phrase)
```

to

```
dispatch.url("https://www.google.com/#q="+phrase)
```

Dispatch and Scalatra base servlet I think have an implementation of url which was clashing. The url version from Scalatra does not return OK.

Comment: You saved me lots of debugging time. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all inspect type of `result`. If you use IDE just hover your mouse on it and see what it is actually is. It must be different than `Future[String]`, it is `Future[T]`, find out what is `T` and how to convert it to String.